# Trying to create a fieldset for each item in a store

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

I'm very new to ExtJS and getting quite lost. I have created a data store -

```
var sections = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    data: [
        {"section" : "One"},
        {"section" : "Two"},
        {"section" : "Three"}
    ]
});
```

What I would like to do now is create a panel for each section, using the section  name (one, two three) as the title.

I have tried a few ways, all of which are really unsuccessful. How do I go about solving this problem?

EDIT - Example of something I tried

```
var sectionStore = Ext.getStore(sections);
var allRecords = sectionStore || sectionStore.data("section");

allRecords.each(function(record) {
    Ext.define('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: record,
        text: record
    })
    console.log(record)
});
```

Comment: as you mentioned *I have tried a few ways, all of which are really unsuccessful* provide your efforts

Comment: Have added an example now.

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.define` defines classes, but you want to create new instances of the `panel` class and add them to the component hierarchy.

So that's what you have to do (you can add them to any existing and already rendered container component):

```
var parentContainer = ... 
var sectionStore = Ext.getStore(sections);
var allRecords = sectionStore || sectionStore.data("section");

allRecords.each(function(record) {
    parentContainer.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: record,
        text: record
    });
});
```

Comment: I shall try this, but what will my parentContainer be? I was this to just display in the main view. Which is currently Ext.define('App.view.main.Main', {
 extend: 'Ext.Panel',
 xtype: 'mainview', ...

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Ext.define('Ext.panel.Panel'`, You just only define a `panel`. Instead of define you need to use `Ext.create()`.

## [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2i6q)

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var sections = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    "section": "One"
                }, {
                    "section": "Two"
                }, {
                    "section": "Three"
                }]
            }),
            fieldSetItems = [];

        sections.each(rec => {
            fieldSetItems.push({
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: rec.get('section')
            });
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Create Items by store',
            items: fieldSetItems,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to do the coding using visual code and then sencha app watch to test. The way the code is created and structured is really different to how it seems to work when using Fiddle.

Comment: So when I try to add this code to VS code, and then run with sencha app watch I get the error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: Man you can do copy paste in your code. It just an example that will help you how to add items dynamically. You need to put your logic based on your requirement.

Comment: For example if your view is created then you can added like this `view.add({
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: rec.get('section')
            }) `.

Comment: Thanks for the example then. I just don't know enough about ExtJS to figure out what to do, and there is no tutorials or guides online so I am stuck.

Comment: But then I get errors telling me that parentContainer is not a function.

Comment: You need to get first `parentContainer` before to use add

Comment: Just for testing use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainview')[0].add({ xtype: 'fieldset', title: 'DEMO' })` in your code.

Comment: How do I set the value of parent container though?

Comment: Have you test this `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainview')[0].add({ xtype: 'fieldset', title: 'DEMO' })`?

Comment: Just tried it now, I get the same error that parentContainer is not a function.

Comment: As I have mentioned that code  there is no `parentContainer` so how do you get this error?

Comment: I hadn't commented out some code you sent earlier. I have commented out now, and the error I get says - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: because it's `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainview')[0]`  undefined. First confirm in which component/view you want to add dynamically

Comment: I want to dynamically add the fieldsets to the main view. Which is - Ext.define('App.view.main.Main', {
 extend: 'Ext.Panel',
 xtype: 'mainview',

Comment: 'Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainview')[0]' I think you're view is not created. You can check with `console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainview')[0])` if it's undefined then first you need to resolve this issue

Comment: Just tested now, it returns undefined. The app was generated using the sencha cmd commands, I am not sure what else I needed to set up, like mainview, I thought it was auto created?

Comment: Check it in `aap.js` file there is define `mainView`

Comment: Yup, it points to the page I was working on - mainView: 'App.view.main.Main'

Comment: I managed to figure something that works slightly out, however it now doesn't should as a fieldset, instead its just a panel with text underneath. Next part is getting it to add text into the one, two, three sections :(

Comment: Now based on your requirement you can choose component from here [ExtJS docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/index.html)

Comment: What do you mean by I can choose component?

Comment: That's means xtype textfield or label or fieldset or any other component